# Why does this quiz question say that protons and electrons do not combine to form neutrons?

Tags: electrons, nuclear-physics, neutrons, protons

I read this somewhere:

> Where are the protons and electrons in a neutron star? When the neutron star forms, most of the protons and electrons combine together to form neutrons.

But on a true/false quiz, I saw the question

> A neutron is formed by an electron and a proton combining together and therefore it is neutral.

but the answer was false. Why are these not contradictory?

Comment: It is unclear what question you are asking. Is the title your question? Or do you want to know the proper reaction equation for the formation of neutrons in a neutron star? Or something else.

Comment: I want to know the proper reaction equation for the formation of neutron in a neutron star

Comment: Under normal conditions when a proton and electron combine you get a hydrogen atom. Only under *extreme* conditions do you get something else like a neutron. So specifying the conditions for the question is important.

Answer (score 41):

You're asking about two distinct phenomena.  The difference between them is subtle, and I think there is some context missing from the second question that you quote, which makes things more confusing than they need to be.

> When the neutron star forms, most of the protons and electrons combine together to form neutrons

This is mostly correct.  The process is known as "electron capture," and the full reaction is

$$\rm p + e^- \to n + \nu_e$$

The other particle in the final state (represented by a [nu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nu_(letter))) is a [neutrino](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutrino).  The neutrino is an uncharged, very low-mass [electron-like particle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lepton), in the same way that neutrons and protons are different charge states of [the same sort of particle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baryon).  So far as we know, in physics, the number of electron-like "leptons" and the number of proton-like "baryons" isn't changed in any physical process.  The neutrinos play an important role in the dynamics of the stellar collapses where neutron stars are formed, but in some authors who write very elementary explanations of neutron stars will leave the neutrinos out of their descriptions.  There are advantages and disadvantages to this approach; your confusion here is one of the disadvantages.

> A neutron is formed by an electron and a proton combining together, therefore it is neutral: true or false? Answer: false

This is a fundamentally flawed true-false question, because it makes several statements at the same time, some of which are correct.  The question I was expecting to find here, based on the title of your question, was more like

> The neutron is an electron and a proton that are "stuck together" somehow.  (Answer: false)

We have [another name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrogen_atom) for an electron and a proton that are semi-permanently "stuck together," and the dynamics of that system are very different from the dynamics of the neutron.

When you "combine together" macroscopic objects in ordinary life, the things that you combined are still somehow present in the combination.  But in particle physics, the situation is different.  The electron-capture process that we're talking about here *fundamentally changes* both the baryon and the lepton parts of the system.  To the extent that a neutron behaves like a composite particle, it behaves as if it is made out of [quarks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quark).

Comment: So where do the neutrinos come from, to facilitate the electron capture?  I was under the impression that they're virtually massless particles that can travel through entire planets without interacting with anything; how do you get an entire star's worth of protons capturing them as they're decaying into a neutron star?

Comment: @MasonWheeler: The neutrino is listed as a product, not a reactant.

Comment: ...oh.  OK, that makes more sense.

Comment: @MasonWheeler although there is a process commonly called "inverse beta decay" where a proton "captures" an antineutrino and transmutes into a neutron while emitting a positron (anti-electron). There are neutrinos whizzing about everywhere, so they are always available for such reactions.

Comment: @thegreatemu Partly true.  Most of the background neutrinos don't have enough energy to drive inverse beta decay.  This is a subject of vigorous discussion in the neutrino detection community.

Comment: I would say that deuterium and tritium can combine to form helium. Is that not correct wording?

Comment: @immibis I would say that a deuteron and a triton can combine to form a helium nucleus and a free neutron.

Comment: The question of true and false was from my ncert science book and a guide answered it false. This was the root of all confusion.

Comment: What makes the statement false? The lack of a neutrino mention or the fact that not all existing neutrons were formed that way? I'd say the statement is odd but essentially true; charge is conserved and 1 - 1 = 0.

Comment: "So far as we know, in physics, the number of electron-like "leptons" and the number of proton-like "baryons" isn't changed in any physical process" -- or to be pedantic, the lepton number isn't changed. Anti-neutrinos count as -1 towards the lepton number. So for example, proton -> neutron + positron + neutrino conserves the lepton number, but someone naively reading that the number of leptons doesn't change might not realise it's possible. Of course if you know electron + positron -> photon then you can figure this out if you happen to think of it :-)

Comment: @JollyJoker: I think the lack of a neutrino does make it false in the context of talking about particle interactions. In a particle interaction leaving out a product is almost as bad as leaving out an input (because of course there's a matching interaction where there is no missing output, but you've missed out the input anti-particle, and then who knows what you're talking about). It's also not OK just to say "a neutron is formed from an outrageously high-energy electron", and leave out the output anti-proton! But with proper context, yeah, the statement would be true *enough* to pass.

Comment: ... I also don't think that's what the question-setter *intended* to be the grounds on which it's false, though. I'm not sure what they did intend the grounds to be, but like rob I suspect it's because they didn't intend "combines together" to mean a weak particle interaction, they intended it to mean "form a system containing a proton and an electron". Or maybe it's false on grounds the reason a neutron is neutral isn't "because" of the proton+electron it's "because" of the up+down+down quarks. It's a bad question "because" the questioner didn't make this clear :-)

Comment: @SteveJessop "A neutron is formed by an electron and a proton combining together" is then false but "A neutron is formed by an electron and a proton combining together (also producing a neutrino but that's irrelevant here)" would be true? :)

Comment: @JollyJoker: basically, yes, provided it is also true that the neutrino is irrelevant here!

Comment: @SteveJessop Re: "don't think that's what the question-setter intended to be the grounds" Ok, I misinterpreted your comment

Answer (score 20):

It's not exactly a myth that protons and electrons combine to form neutrons, but it's not very accurate. A proton and electron can react to produce a neutron, but a neutron isn't simply a composite particle consisting of a proton joined to an electron.

Protons and neutrons are hadrons, which means they consist of [quarks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quark). A proton has 2 up quarks & 1 down quark, a neutron has 1 up quark and 2 down quarks. Quarks are bound together by [gluons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gluon) (and a bunch of virtual quarks, but don't worry about them for now). Hadrons consisting of 3 (or a higher odd number) quarks are also known as baryons.

When a proton & electron react an up quark in the proton is converted to a down quark, and the electron is converted to a [neutrino](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutrino). This process is mediated by a $W^+$ boson. I can't find a good diagram of this exact process, but here's a diagram from [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_interaction#Charged-current_interaction) of a closely related process: the decay of a neutron into a proton, electron, and antineutrino.

[image: neutron decay]

The diagram for the proton + electron reaction is very similar, just reverse the time direction, and swap the $W^-$ to a $W^+$, and the antineutrino to a neutrino.

Comment: Under CPT symmetry, aren't those two diagrams actually the same diagram?

Comment: @Yakk Indeed! Which is why I thought it appropriate to post that image.